# It is posible in OdooV12 to create a WEB form?

Tags: forms, web, odoo

I'm developing my company's website with Odoo and I need to get data though input and then save it into a model. I have defined a simple model,controller and template but I'm not able to make the treatment of the data to save it in the BD.

```
#model
class AcademyTeacher(models.Model):
    _name = 'academy.teacher'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    date = fields.Date(string="BIrthday")

#controler
@http.route('/prueba_form', auth='public', website=True)
def fun_product3(self):
    return http.request.render('web_prueba.form_prueba', {})

#template
<template id="form_prueba">
            <t t-call="website.layout">
                <body> 
                    <div class="container text-center">
                        <div class="page">
                            <div class="row">
                                <form>
                                    <input type="text" name="Name" />
                                    <input type="date" name="Birth date"/>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </t>
        </template>
```

I'm not sure if the template have to be defined with simple HTML or it has to be used Odoo tags.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't have the time to answer your question fully, because it isn't done with a short answer. But i will give you a hint: look into Odoo's module [website_crm](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/e5b7b8248cc435331dfdf85a2aae75e93b547796/addons/website_crm). It is changing the "contact us" page to something you could find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add simple HTML tags in the template file. In the XML file, you can access object of your model and also it's data.

If you want to create a simple form using the template then you can use ajax call on button click event. You don't need to write `body` tag again in template like below.

```
<t t-call="website.layout">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="row">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" />
                    <input type="date" name="Birth date"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
```